# How to split a 1d numpy array into a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have a numpy array that is one dimensional but each elements contains numbers and letters. I want to split up each elemnt so I can get the specific numbers I need. Code below:

```
    my_array = [' profile    : (   99.27,    99.19)   20.82      1.75    4.40    0.86    22.05\n'
    ' profile    : (   99.80,    99.04)   22.82      1.00    5.02    0.79    33.88\n'  
    ' sersic    : (  100.15,    99.59)   25.23      1.79    4.00    0.58   -53.98\n'
    ' sersic    : (  100.31,    99.45)   18.97     10.22    3.00    0.35   -73.86\n']
```

So as seen in the example above, my code considers my array to have 4 elements. I want to split up each element such that I can get the 3rd, 4th and 5th numbers (so in this example I would like to get 20.82, 1.75, 4.40, 22.82, 1, 5.02 etc...).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using an array for this to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to go through the lines and split to break them down into substrings, then pick out the values you want (from then end seems easier) and convert them to float:

```
my_array = [
' profile    : (   99.27,    99.19)   20.82      1.75    4.40    0.86    22.05\n',
' profile    : (   99.80,    99.04)   22.82      1.00    5.02    0.79    33.88\n',  
' sersic    : (  100.15,    99.59)   25.23      1.79    4.00    0.58   -53.98\n',
' sersic    : (  100.31,    99.45)   18.97     10.22    3.00    0.35   -73.86\n'
]

matrix = [ list(map(float,line.split()[-5:-2])) for line in my_array]
```

output:

```
print(matrix)

[
  [20.82, 1.75, 4.4], 
  [22.82, 1.0, 5.02], 
  [25.23, 1.79, 4.0], 
  [18.97, 10.22, 3.0]
]
```